# Excel - VBA - ExportAsFixedFormat PDF File Size too Large

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, acrobat

Using a macro to save a copy of a worksheet as a PDF to my desktop.  However, the actual file size when using my macro results in a file size two or three times larger then if I were to manually, in Excel, go to the Acrobat tab and create PDF.  I need to reduce the file size of the pdf further.  I've set a small print area, tried using minimumquality, reducing image sizes before hand, etc.  Is there a better alternative to print a PDF of a worksheet with a smaller file size?  The difference between files is 100kb compared to 280kb.

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, Filename:="C:\
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem with file sizes in the past, when I've needed to programmtically create .pdf's from Excel files.

One work-around, although not an especially elegant one, might be to programmatically simulate the exact keyboard/mouse actions that are required to manually save the file as a .pdf, using SENDKEYS.

The end result should be the acceptable image quality and smaller file size that you get by going through the process manually.

The exact sequence of keys might vary depending on your particular machine, excel version, etc... but you could try doing something like this:

```
Application.SendKeys "%fy1{Enter}"
```

You probably have to play around with the sequence of keystrokes that you are attempting to simulate. But that should do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that's actually a pretty great idea and probably works better universally than what I did to solve it.  I ended up finding some VBA code on another forum that uses the AdobePDFMaker software and calls upon it to create the PDF.  The only issue with this is that it needs the machine of the User to activate a module in VBA and have an up-to-date version of Adobe running.  However, it worked great for what I needed it for.  I think your answer would also have worked as a great alternative!  Thanks for taking the time to answer.